# Ionic firebase facebook auth

Tags: cordova, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

I have login page with Facebook (I am working with Firebase Auth) and when I run my app on my device and click on the login button I get the error message:

> This operation is not supported in the environment this application is running on. "location.protocol" must be http or https and web storage must be enabled.

and the error code is:

```
auth/operation-not-supported-in-this-environment
```

If I run this app in my Google Chrome, its working great. Where is the problem?

Thanks.

Login Code:

```
var provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
    firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
      // This gives you a Facebook Access Token. You can use it to access the Facebook API.
      var token = result.credential.accessToken;
      // The signed-in user info.
      var user = result.user;
      console.log(user);
      // ...
    }).catch(function(error) {
      // Handle Errors here.

      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;
     console.log(errorMessage);
     console.log(errorCode);
      var email = error.email;
      // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
      var credential = error.credential;
      // ...
    });
```

Comment: signInWithPopup is not supported in Cordova right now. As a workaround you could use a Facebook sign-in library for Cordova and then call signInWithCredential() with the access token.

Comment: How Can I do it? you have an exapmle? @ChanningHuang

Answer (score 1):

As Channing said, currently this is not supported in Cordova.
You need to use a Cordova plugin for facebook sign in.
On success, you will get an OAuth 2 access token or id token.
You then initialize an auth credential and call signInWithCredential using the web sdk:

```js
firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(fbAccessToken)).then(function(user) {
  // The facebook user is now signed in.
}).catch(function(error) {
  // Some error happened!
});
```

To get the fb access token, you can use for example the following plugin i found: https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin

Comment: I can get the acces token but the promise seems not to be working. Does'nt resolve nor catch any error. Don't know how to debug that since this is running in the emulator. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Ok, finally i discovered 'monitor' in the android sdk to debug the emulator. The error was pretty stupid, i wasn't importing firebase in the component. Monitor showed me something like Reference error firebase... Anyway, your answer was pretty useful and was the key of discovering many things. Thanks a lot.